# Odoo 8 module fec not available after update

Tags: odoo-8

I have Odoo 8 installed on my synology NAS.
It is working properly and I wanted to install an additional module for FEC (l10n_fr_fec) and downloaded the module and placed the downloaded files in the dedicated /addons folder next to all other modules.
I checked the path in the openerp-server.conf file.
I tried updating modules through the Odoo functionality but the new module doesn't appear.
I restarted Odoo. I checked again and still no new module.
Even though I can see all 229 other modules (most of them not installed) and thier names are matching all subfolders of the addons directory, I can't see the new one.
Please advice

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the owner and the access rights of the module folder/files is the same as the other modules.

You can also start your odoo server adding theses parameters `-d your_database -i l10n_fr_fec`
it will try to install during startup and you will see a potential error in the logs

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I am not sure how to check the access rights for folders in the /@appstore folder since it is hidden and I can't see it in the File Station of my DSM or in the Volumes.

Comment: Also where do I add these parameters you mentionned? I usually restart Odoo from my DSM interface using a click on a restart button.

Comment: To check the access right you should connect with ssh to your NAS, then go in the dedicated /addons folder and do a 'ls -l' command to see the owners and access rights of your addons.

Comment: Your odoo is probably launched as a service , you should find a odoo or openerp service fil in /etc/init.d

Comment: but to manually test you have to stop your odoo service and launch it manually with a command like this one (in the folder where you installed it): "odoo-bin -c /your/config/file/path -d your_database -i l10n_fr_fec"

Comment: you'll find more here : [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/cmdline.html)

Comment: Indeed all directories are owned by ODOO8, except for the one containing the addon l10n_fr_fec which is own by root since I copied it myself directly via Putty

Comment: I could't find the file init.d anywhere. When I type the suggested command line "odoo-bin -c ..." in Putty, I have an error message "-ash: odoo-bin: command not found". Please help (I know I am completely novice with all this)